# change divs order with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have code like this:

```
<div>
<div id="div1" class="flex">test 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="flex">test 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="flex">test 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="flex">test 4</div></div>
```

How to do something line that: when somebody clicks the div with "flex" class, this div go to the top of the "list". For example, if i click the div with id "div3" the order of elements should be: div3, div1, div2, div4.

I dont want to append the parent div or inner HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a div with id `#first` before the divs, then use jQuery's `insertAfter()`

```
$(".flex").click(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter( "#first" );
});

<div>
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="div1" class="flex">test 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="flex">test 2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="flex">test 3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="flex">test 4</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/etgm865x/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without adding a new `div` and using [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/). 
Just given an `id` to parent `div`.

Inserting before the first child of the parent `div`

```js
$(".flex").click(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('main').children[0];
  if (!($(this)).is(element)) { //Checks if its first div or not
    $(this).insertBefore(element);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1" class="flex">test 1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="flex">test 2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="flex">test 3</div>
  <div id="div4" class="flex">test 4</div>
</div>
```

Note: used [jQuery 1.7.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/03/21/jquery-1-7-2-released/)